# ExtJS Load Data on Ajax return (json) and load store for grid.panel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, extjs

The code below works normally Loading data MyData variable, but need to get the data that comes from page in php and click on store feed the grid. 
in my page php, it generate a code json, and ajax save its in variable data, in alert (javascript) it show information.

Since now, thanks;

```
    pdvs : function () {

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url : "relpontovendaper.php",
        dataType : "json",
        success : function (data) {
            alert(data[1].nome);
        }
    });
});

   // return php    [ { "nome": "Claudemir", "sobrenome": "Feliciano" }, { "nome":                                   "Mario Borges" , "sobrenome": "Juno" } ] 

var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        fields : ['name', 'area']
    });

//This is Load.
var myData = [['Maria', 'santos'],
    ['Lucas', 'pereira'],
    ['Mariana', 'fagundes']];

var store = new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
        fields : [
            'nome',
            'sobrenome'
        ]
    });

// this load in grid
store.loadData(myData);

//this dont load in grid  - informations of ajax in format json
store.loadData(data);

Ext.getCmp("_relpontoperiodo_grid").getStore().loadData(myData);

    }
   //This is a item (window)
    items : [{
    xtype : "grid",
    id : "_relpontoperiodo_grid",
    height : 230,
    width : 200,
    store : new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
        fields : [
            'nome',
            'sobrenome'
        ]
    }),
    columns : [{
            header : "PDV_COD",
            sortable : true,
            dataIndex : 'nome'
        }, {
            header : "PDV_DESCRIÇÃO",
            sortable : true,
            dataIndex : 'sobrenome',
            flex : 1
        }
    ]
        }
        ]
```

Comment: Not sure i completely understand the question.  Are you trying to retrieve `data` via `ajax` and to `insert` this data into the `store`?

Comment: Yes , thats right, because I'll load this store in grid

Comment: I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve `data` remotely (from `php` in this case) you can add a proxy to the store.  Here is an example:

```
var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        fields : ['name', 'area'],
        autoLoad:true, //this will autoLoad the store on load.  Or you can call                    
                       //store.load() later.
        proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'relpontovendaper.php',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: ''
        }
    }
    });
```

[More info is available on sencha docs.](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonStore)

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({        
        url : "/php/sge/relpontovendaper.php",
        dataType : "json",
        success : function (data) {
            alert(data[1].nome);                
            //store.loadData(data);
            Ext.getCmp("_relpontoperiodo_grid").getStore().loadData(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This solution is using `jquery` to handle the `AJAX` request.  `Ext JS` has built in functionality to handle the request so the preferred method for an `ext` app is to leverage either a [proxy](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-proxy) or [Ext.Ajax.request](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Ajax-method-request)